# adding an if statement to javascript?

Tags: javascript

Can someone please help me? I am trying to add an if statement to my JavaScript so if welcome_page2 div is hidden or not visible, then run the function, otherwise don't run the function.

Can someone please show me where I'm going wrong? Thanks.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if ($('.welcome_page2').is(":hidden")) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            var cvr = document.getElementById("cover")
            var dlg = document.getElementById("dialog")
            cvr.style.display = "block"
            dlg.style.display = "block"
            if (document.body.style.overflow = "hidden") {
                cvr.style.width = "1024"
                cvr.style.height = "100&#37;"
            }
        }, 3000);
</script>
```

Comment: This is your third (fairly basic) question in an hour, are you even trying to figure things out yourself or just hoping random strangers will do your work for you?

Comment: Hint: The answer lies in the difference between an assignment and a comparison operator. Look at your if statement.

Answer (score 3):

balance your braces, i.e.

```
        ....
        cvr.style.height = "100&#37;"
     }
   }, 3000);
} // close your if
```

Like so

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if  ($('.welcome_page2').is(":hidden")) {
     setTimeout(function () {
        var cvr = document.getElementById("cover")
        var dlg = document.getElementById("dialog")
        cvr.style.display = "block"
        dlg.style.display = "block"
        if (document.body.style.overflow = "hidden") {
            cvr.style.width = "1024"
            cvr.style.height = "100&#37;"
         }
    }, 3000);
} // end if
</script>
```

Answer (score -2):

```
if  ($('.welcome_page2').is(":hidden"))
{
    setTimeout(function ()
    {
        var cvr = document.getElementById("cover")
        var dlg = document.getElementById("dialog")
        cvr.style.display = "block"
        dlg.style.display = "block"
        if (document.body.style.overflow = "hidden")
        {
            cvr.style.width = "1024"
            cvr.style.height = "100&#37;"
        }
    }, 3000);
}
```